# "a word that is identical to an alias being expanded is not expanded a second time"

Tags: bash, shell, alias

Bash manual says

> The first word of the replacement text is tested for aliases, but a
>   word that is **identical to an alias being expanded** is not expanded a
>   second time. This means that one may alias `ls` to `ls -F`, for
>   instance, and Bash does not try to recursively expand the replacement
>   text.

I'm trying to figure out which alias follows "identical to" in the quote,

- any alias being expanded in the same sequence of alias expansion recursions, or
- the alias whose expansion was first started, or
- the alias whose expansion was last started.

So I create  an example

```
$ alias a1=a2; 
$ alias a2=a3;
$ alias a3=a4;
```

and want to check the alias expansion result of `a1`, in the following cases

```
$ alias a4=a1;
```

or

```
$ alias a4=a2;
```

or

```
$ alias a4=a3;
```

How can I check the alias expansion result of `a1`, possibly by performing alias expansion on `a1` without letting the shell going further than alias expansion?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely grok the question but my interpretation is just that, for `a1=...`, when literal `a1` itself is encountered in the alias definition it is simply ignored (until the next step of command resolution/execution)... and no matter how many nested levels deep it's encountered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What the manual says is that the shell will avoid any loop that may be caused by recursion of alias expansion.

With your example (`a1=a2=a3=a4`), if you execute `alias a4=a1` you are creating a loop. Then, as soon as you will execute `a1` (resp. `a2`, `a3`, `a4`), once the shell loops back to `a1` (resp. `a2`, `a3`, `a4`) it will search for a command named `a1` (resp. `a2`, `a3`, `a4`) that is NOT an alias (since that would create a never-ending loop).

Example:

```
$ a1() { echo Phew, I got out of the loop; }
$ alias a1='echo "(a1)"; a2' a2='echo "(a2)"; a3'
$ alias a3='echo "(a3)"; a4' a4='echo "(a4)"; a1'

$ a1
(a1)
(a2)
(a3)
(a4)
Phew, I got out of the loop

$ a2                              # Command a2 does not exist anywhere
(a2)
(a3)
(a4)
(a1)
a2: command not found
```

Comment: Thanks. When I change `a4='echo "(a4)"; a1'` to  `a4='echo "(a4)"; a2'`, running `a1` doesn't output anything. Wondering why...

Comment: @Tim On my system (`bash` 4.3), doing so gives an output that is roughly similar to my second example.

Comment: Thanks. I got your result in a new terminal. Maybe something is messed up in the original terminal.

Comment: *Brilliant* illustration.  Wow.

Answer (score 1):

```
:> alias e="echo "
:> alias text=foo
:> e text
foo
```

Technically the shell does go further than alias expansion but nonetheless I think this is what you meant.

Comment: @ADDB Unfortunately you think wrong. And it would have been easy for you to try it out before posting, wouldn't it? `alias echo="echo foo" ; alias e=echo ; e`