# how does bash alias expansion work?

Tags: bash, alias

I have the following lines in my `.bash_aliases` file

```
alias enw='emacsclient -nw'
alias gie='enw ~/.config/git/ignore'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

and I don't understand how and why they all work (they do!).

The second alias uses the first, which means that expansion has to be performed repeatedly to get an actual command. In fact, I can observe this by writing `gie` in the terminal and pressing `Ctrl+Alt+e` to expand manually. After pressing it once I get `enw ~/.config/git/ignore`, and after pressing it again I get `emacsclient -nw ~/.config/git/ignore`. However, an expansion strategy that simply expands until there's nothing to expand wouldn't work for the third alias since it's recursive, and the third alias works nevertheless.

If bash can expand nested aliases, how does it avoid non-termination? Does it simply stop after a fixed number of steps? Or does it stop after it encounters the same alias twice in an expansion chain?

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384181/a-word-that-is-identical-to-an-alias-being-expanded-is-not-expanded-a-second-ti) answer your question? (Summary: it stops after it encounters the same alias twice.)

Comment: yes, thanks! if you add an answer i'll accept it. in fact I had already looked at the manual, but must have overlooked the "not expanded a second time" line.

Comment: It's better to mark it as a duplicate question, to avoid having to duplicate the answer.