# Is escaping shell aliases in scripts useful when executing scripts?

Tags: bash, shell-script, alias

Does escaping `bash` aliases make any sense in any - not sourced and normally run - shell scripts?

---

Consider the simplest situation with `ls` for which many users have re-defined its functioning with an `alias` (in `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases`), e.g. like:

```sh
alias ls='\ls --color=auto --group-directories-first'
```

---

And then suppose I call a shell script of mine containing a function, e.g. like:

```sh
list_sata_devices ()
{
    \ls -1 /dev/sd?
}
```

---

As you noticed I forced *the original* `ls` with `\ls`, but is there any need for this I wonder?

---

Of course, one could write it without using `ls`, e.g like:

```sh
list_sata_devices ()
{
    printf '%s\n' /dev/sd?
}
```

But I still hesitate what possible difference might there be.

Comment: "As you noticed I forced the original ls with \ls, but is there any need for this I wonder?" > https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384181/70524

Comment: @Cbhihe I'm responding specifically to the part I quoted, which is independent of the rest

Comment: @Cbhihe all of that is irrelevant to the part I quoted. When an alias is being expanded, any word that's already undergoing alias expansion is excluded from further expansion. So in an alias `ls` whose expansion contains `ls`, the `ls` in the expansion is not considered for alias expansion. Which is exactly what the linked post is discussing. There's no point to escaping `ls` inside an alias itself names `ls`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> alias ls='\ls --color=auto --group-directories-first'
> ```

No need for the backslash, [the shell doesn't fall into such a trivial loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#:%7E:text=The%20first%20word%20of%20the%20replacement%20text%20is%20tested%20for%20aliases,%20but%20a%20word%20that%20is%20identical%20to%20an%20alias%20being%20expanded%20is%20not%20expanded%20a%20second%20time):

> The first word of the replacement text is tested for aliases, but a word that  is
> identical  to  an  alias  being expanded is not expanded a second time.

---

> And then suppose I call a shell script of mine containing a function,
> e.g. like:
>
> ```
> list_sata_devices ()
> {
>     \ls -1 /dev/sd?
> }
> ```

If it's a shell script, i.e. a non-interactive shell, [then aliases are disabled by default](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#:%7E:text=Aliases%20are%20not%20expanded%20when%20the%20shell%20is%20not%20interactive):

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see The Shopt Builtin).

The script would need to explicitly enable them ([`shopt -s expand_aliases`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)) Even if it does so (for whatever reason), it won't inherit any aliases set in your interactive shell, and a non-interactive shell doesn't read e.g. `.bashrc` either, so it won't get them from there. [A non-interactive shell does read the file named in `$BASH_ENV`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#:%7E:text=When%20Bash%20is%20started%20non-interactively), though, so maybe don't set aliases there.

So, no need for the backslash here, either.

---

> ```
> list_sata_devices ()
> {
>     printf '%s\n' /dev/sd?
> }
> ```

Well, this is a different command. Not by much in effect, but `ls` might treat some special characters differently if printing to a terminal.

Anyway, Bash *can* [export and inherit  *functions*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#:%7E:text=Functions%20may%20be%20exported%20so%20that%20subshells%20automatically%20have%20them%20defined%20with%20the%20-f%20option%20to%20the%20export%20builtin) through the environment, which could mess up a script, but one doesn't usually do that accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

Your context is such that you want to execute a script in its environment rather than sourcing it in the calling shell. 
In that case there is no need to escape any command name in script, even though that name may be previously aliased.

Aliases are not carried over to script environment without sourcing the file that contains their definitions.

A script is not an interactive shell, so the usefulness of defining aliases in a script is questionable as their role is primarily one of convenience in an interactive context.  Being (hopefully) easy to remember abbreviations, cmd-aliases basically ease interactivity between human and machine (read "they spare you a lot of memorizing long commands, and typing in terminal window").

So I would not in general use predefined aliases in a script for a number of reasons: (i) script readability, and (ii) to keep full control over your script and what it does without an external alias defining what goes and goes not in your script. Imagine writing a script based on an alias defined elsewhere and months or weeks later modifying that alias definition without remembering that your old script actually depended on it...  It's a good thing that aliases are not carried over by default into scripts executed in sub-shells.

Additionally, from `man bash`, when inside a function, an alias is expanded only after the function is read and becomes available **after** the function is executed. So in practice if you were to define an alias in a script (I generally wouldn't, but there may be exceptional use-cases), the best place to do so would be on a different line **above** the function or any cmd using said alias (here consider that a function is seen as a command by the execution shell).

Last and  unrelated to scripts, @muru's top comment is completely valid as also found in the Bash manual. If an alias' expansion includes its own name, occurrence of the very alias' name in the expansion does not lead to a new expansion of that name, etc. This would cause an infinite recursion. So you might see but will never need to write: `alias ls='\ls --color=auto --group-directories-first'`. Instead simply write: `alias ls='ls --color=auto --group-directories-first'`.

However escaping a previously aliased name may be useful, but in different cases, such as:

```
  alias ls='ls -A --color=auto --group-directories-first'
  alias ll='\ls -l --color=auto'
```

In the above case, if you did not escape the `ls` in the `ll` alias, it would include flags and options defined in the first line defining the `ls` alias, something you may or may not want.  This tells you that chaining aliases is ok, recursion is not.

---

*EDIT:* Answer to your last question on the difference between `ls -1 <foo*>` and `printf '%s\n <foo*>`.

For instance in a specific x86_64 box running Gnu Bash v5.1.4:

```
 $ time for i in $(seq 10000); do \ls -1 /dev/sd* 1> /dev/null; done
 real    0m17.420s
 user    0m10.910ss
 sys     0m7.598s

 $ time for i in $(seq 10000); do printf '%s\n' /dev/sd*  1> /dev/null; done
 real    0m0.574s
 user    0m0.285s
 sys     0m0.287s
```

Executing `ls` is time consuming even if it is built-in because of [how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204211/4906636). I am not good on the particulars of its implementation though beyond the fact that it uses `lstat()` when file permissions are involved.

Comment: where did subshells come into this? There don't seem to be any in the question, and it shouldn't matter if they run a simple `ls` in one or not? A completely separate script isn't a subshell.